# mapping geo_point from MongoDB to Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mapping

I'm trying to use Kibana to see location info as a geo_point. Data has already transfered from Mongodb to ElasticSearch. The data looks like this in Mongodb:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "location" : "42.2734, -83.7133", "dst_ip" : "192.168.79.136", "src_ip" : "35.139.46.72" }
```

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166978/mongodb-elasticsearch-mapping-to-geopoint) like mine, so I use string type in Mongodb, but in ElasticSearch the value of "location" is also string.

So, how do I map the values that should be stored as a geo_point?

Comment: I know it's not your question but location is a "string" `"location" : "42.2734, -83.7133"` which will do you no good for MongoDB. See [Location Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#location-data) from the Geospatial Indexes and Queries documentation. So whatever information you read is leading you astray.

Answer (score 0):

You should create proper mapping in ES first, smth like

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You need this because ES is not schema-less, and data interpreted, analyzed and processed at index time. After this, you can index data in form you already have - comma separated string with coords is just fine.

See [geo point docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your answers. However, I need sync data from MongoDB to Elasticsearch, so I don't manually push 1 record to with the PUT command you gave.

Comment: This command is to create mapping. You run it once per your index lifetime. ES is not schemaless, like Mongo. So you need to specify field types ahead (before adding data). Once you did so, you can reindex/sync data in any manner you want. If you don't specify field types explicitly, ES does this implicitly for you, and ES treats "42.2734, -83.7133" like simple string.